# run .sql file over a collection of databases on an instance

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\LS\\SmartStats.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

I'm not sure where I pilfered this code from but it worked on a single database.

I'm new to C#.

I want to be able to call any .sql file from inside or outside the app. Can't I just string the .sql file and do a foreach over a collection of databases on any given instance?

Comment: If you need to dynamically collect the list of databases on the sever, you need to use the SMO API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx.  From this object, you can get a collection of databases.

Comment: Not real helpful Brain. I can read canned code examples. I need the advice of a C# coder.

Comment: what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: give a valid example of the file contents also I would seriously look into utilizing stored procedures this is what things like this are designed for..

Comment: To call a stored proc over a list of databases would require the proc be in every database first. Thank you though.

Comment: Simon. I've been able to use the code I posted and run the .sql file against a single db. I actually found that code here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

//reference the following assemplyies of SMO

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc

Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo

Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

//        using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

//using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

```
    public static void  ExecuteScript(string fname, List<string> databases)
    {
        string script = File.ReadAllText(fname);
        ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection("server-name/instance", "user", "password");

        Server SMOServer = new Server(conn);

        // foreach (Database db in SMOServer.Databases) //for all databases in server
        foreach (var dbname in databases)
        {               
            var db = SMOServer.Databases[dbname];
            var ds = db.ExecuteWithResults(script); //if you want query result as a Dataset
          //db.ExecuteNonQuery(script); // if you run non return query result, e.g update/insert/delete
        }
        conn.Disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you have the list of databases somewhere that you need to iterate over and that you can figure that part out.

Once you do that, the secret to making this work is the SQL `USE` statement. You just need to add this dynamically at the top of the script and everything should work correctly.

For example:

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\LS\\SmartStats.sql");
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

        var databaseNames = new List<String> {"database1", "database2"};
        foreach (var databaseName in databaseNames)
        {
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("USE " + databaseName + Environment.NewLine + "GO" + Environment.NewLine + script);
        }
```

Comment: Actually, I won't know the list of databases... but this is exactly the direction I was going.

Comment: @mikewestatl, query `sys.databases` to get the list of instance databases. Just exclude system databases (master, model, tempdb plus SSISDB and distributor).

Comment: Yep. Doing that already Dan. Thanks. I'm have trouble iterating over that list once i get it.  Thank you though.